# how to restart process in pool when hit exception in python

Tags: python, python-asyncio, multiprocess

```
import signal
import asyncio
import os
import random
import time
import multiprocessing

my_list = []
for i in range(0,10):
    n = random.randint(1,100)
    my_list.append(n)


async def loop_item(my_item):
    while True:
        a = random.randint(1, 2)
        if a == 2:
            print(f"process id: {os.getpid()}")
            raise Exception('Error')
        print(f"process id: {os.getpid()} - {my_item}")
        time.sleep(0.5)


def run_loop(my_item):
    asyncio.run(loop_item(my_item))


def throw_error(e):
    os.system('bash /root/my-script.sh')  #that launchs "python my-script.py"
    os.killpg(os.getpgid(os.getpid()), signal.SIGKILL)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10)
    for my_item in my_list:
        pool.apply_async(run_loop, (my_item,), error_callback=throw_error)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

this is my demo code  ,  in which it will create a `my_list` with 10 items in it as random number

then launch with 10 processes to print it out to alone with pid

then I add a `raise Exception` to mimic any kind of exception it may occur and want to restart this `loop_item(my_item)` function in new process if exception happens

there are two obstacle for this , one is pass the variable `my_item` but I think I should be able to make it work with external tool like Redis that put/get variable , but any better idea is appreciated.

what really stops me is how to effectively launch the process again after it hit exception and exited

so far I was able to use `throw_error` function to kill the python script itself or launch another shell script to kill and launch python script again , but this approach seems to be less efficient

so I am wondering if there is a better way to restart one except'ed process instead of restart the whole script ?

one way I tried , was creating a new process pool in `throw_error` function ,like

```
def throw_error(e):
    pool2 = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)
    pool2.apply_async(run_loop, (my_item,), error_callback=throw_error)
    pool2.close()
    pool2.join()
```

but it seems to be an bad idea as after multiple exceptions , the process pools are getting out of controls , and accumulated up to hundreds if not thousands "zombie" processes

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is one of [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

This answer is to suggest an alternative design that could solve problem X, not solving problem Y - aka restarting process in pool.

---

As far as I know Python doesn't have good control over graceful termination of the spawned subprocesses or threads that's already running.

So, the best approach would be - just not letting each process/thread fail completely and propagating error in the first place.

Such can be achieved by writing a small wrapper, where you wrap a function inside `try-except` block with `Exception` - which then will catch any Exception it encounters. Then we can retry using one `while` loop.

```py
def wrapper(func, max_retries, data):
    """
    Wrapper adding retry capabilities to workload.

    Args:
        func: function to execute.
        max_retries: Maximum retries until moving on.
        data: data to process.

    Returns:
        (Input data, result) Tuple.
    """

    # wrap in while in case for retry.
    retry_count = 0
    while retry_count <= max_retries:  # while true: if you want infinite loop
        retry_count += 1

        # try to process data
        try:
            result = func(data)
        except Exception as err:
            # on exception save result as error and retry
            result = err
        else:
            # otherwise it was successful, break out of retry loop
            break

    # return result
    return data, result
```

---

Here's some dumb demo code testing this idea, with half the failure chance.

```py
import logging
import functools
import random
from os import getpid
from multiprocessing import Pool


logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)-8s %(message)s", level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger()


def wrapper(func, max_retries, data):
    """
    Wrapper adding retry capabilities to workload with some fancy output.

    Args:
        func: function to execute.
        max_retries: Maximum retries until moving on.
        data: data to process.

    Returns:
        (Input data, result) Tuple.
    """
    pid = f"{getpid():<6}"
    logger.info(f"[{pid}]  Processing {data}")

    # just a line to satisfy pylint
    result = None

    # wrap in while in case for retry.
    retry_count = 0

    while retry_count <= max_retries:
        # try to process data
        try:
            result = func(data)
        except Exception as err:
            # on exception print out error, set result as err, then retry
            logger.error(
                f"[{pid}]  {err.__class__.__name__} while processing {data}, "
                f"{max_retries - retry_count} retries left. "
            )
            result = err
        else:
            break

        retry_count += 1

    # print and return result
    logger.info(f"[{pid}]  Processing {data} done")
    return data, result


class RogueAIException(Exception):
    pass


def workload(n):
    """
    Quite rebellious Fibonacci function
    """

    if random.randint(0, 1):
        raise RogueAIException("I'm sorry Dave, I'm Afraid I can't do that.")

    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n - 1):
        a, b = b, a + b

    return b


def main():
    data = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(20)]

    # fix parameters. Decorator can't be pickled, we'll have to live with this.
    wrapped_workload = functools.partial(wrapper, workload, 3)

    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        # apply function for each data
        results = pool.map(wrapped_workload, data)

        print("\nInput Output")
        for fed_data, result in results:
            print(f"{fed_data:<6}{result}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 40
ERROR    [13904 ]  RogueAIException while processing 40, 3 retries left. 
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 40 done
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 93
ERROR    [13904 ]  RogueAIException while processing 93, 3 retries left. 
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 93 done
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 96
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 96 done
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 48
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 48 done
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 17
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 17 done
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 52
ERROR    [13904 ]  RogueAIException while processing 52, 3 retries left. 
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 52 done
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 96
ERROR    [13904 ]  RogueAIException while processing 96, 3 retries left. 
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 96 done
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 23
ERROR    [13904 ]  RogueAIException while processing 23, 3 retries left. 
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 23 done
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 99
ERROR    [13904 ]  RogueAIException while processing 99, 3 retries left. 
ERROR    [13904 ]  RogueAIException while processing 99, 2 retries left.
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 99 done
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 55
ERROR    [13904 ]  RogueAIException while processing 55, 3 retries left.
ERROR    [13904 ]  RogueAIException while processing 55, 2 retries left.
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 55 done
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 63
ERROR    [13904 ]  RogueAIException while processing 63, 3 retries left.
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 63 done
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 61
INFO     [25180 ]  Processing 3
ERROR    [13904 ]  RogueAIException while processing 61, 3 retries left.
INFO     [25180 ]  Processing 3 done
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 61 done
INFO     [25180 ]  Processing 42
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 33
ERROR    [25180 ]  RogueAIException while processing 42, 3 retries left.
ERROR    [13904 ]  RogueAIException while processing 33, 3 retries left.
ERROR    [25180 ]  RogueAIException while processing 42, 2 retries left.
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 33 done
ERROR    [25180 ]  RogueAIException while processing 42, 1 retries left.
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 2
INFO     [25180 ]  Processing 42 done
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 2 done
INFO     [25180 ]  Processing 35
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 45
INFO     [25180 ]  Processing 35 done
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 45 done
INFO     [25180 ]  Processing 2
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 11
ERROR    [25180 ]  RogueAIException while processing 2, 3 retries left.
ERROR    [13904 ]  RogueAIException while processing 11, 3 retries left.
INFO     [25180 ]  Processing 2 done
ERROR    [13904 ]  RogueAIException while processing 11, 2 retries left.
ERROR    [13904 ]  RogueAIException while processing 11, 1 retries left.
ERROR    [13904 ]  RogueAIException while processing 11, 0 retries left.
INFO     [13904 ]  Processing 11 done

Input Output
40    102334155
93    12200160415121876738
96    51680708854858323072
48    4807526976
17    1597
52    32951280099
96    51680708854858323072
23    28657
99    218922995834555169026
55    139583862445
63    6557470319842
61    2504730781961
3     2
42    267914296
33    3524578
2     1
35    9227465
2     1
45    1134903170
11    I'm sorry Dave, I'm Afraid I can't do that.
```

Comment: This is a very good answer to implement some basic retry mechanism. OP should have marked it as accepted.

Comment: @HienPham Glad I nailed it, haha! I'm pretty sure there gotta be better ways than what I guessed - unless it introduce too much complexity.